# Spark- scan data frame base on value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to find a column (I do know the name of the column) base on a value. For example in this dataframe below, I'd like to know which row that has a column contains `yellow` for `Category = A` . The thing is I don't know the column name (colour) in advance so I couldn't do `select * where Category = 'A' and colour = 'yellow'` How can I scan the columns and achieve this? Many thanks for your help.

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|Category|colour     |.      name. |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|A.      |      blue.|         Elmo|
|A       |    yellow |         Alex|
|B       |      desc |         Erin|
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop that check through the list of column names. You also can wrap this loop in a function for the readable purpose. Please note that this check per column would happen **in sequence**.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = df.columns

for c in cols:
    cnt = df.where((F.col('Category') == 'A') & (F.col(c) == 'yellow')).count()
    if cnt > 0:
        print(c)
```